# React.createClass vs. ES6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React and trying to get a handle on syntax.

I'm developing in a React 15 environment (using the react-starterify template) and have been using the syntax in VERSION 2 below, but, most of the examples and tutorials I find in Facebook's React pages are VERSION 1. What's the difference between the two and when should I use the one over the other?

**VERSION 1**

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul>
        // some list
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = MyOtherComponent;
```

**VERSION 2**

```
const MyComponent = () => (
  <ul>
    // some list
  </ul>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: The first version allows you to hook into lifecycle methods like `componenDidMount`, `shouldComponentUpdate` etc. The second version is basically just the `render` function. Use version 2 by default and if you need lifecycle methods, use version 1.

Comment: Also note that `createClass` is the old class style, now you can (should) use [ES6 classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).

Comment: Also createClass has been deprecated in react native.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The second code is a *stateless functional component* and is a new syntax/pattern for defining components as a function of `props`. It was introduced in React v0.14.

You can read more about it on the official React Blog, [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#stateless-functional-components), on the official React Documentation, [**here**](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions).

> These components behave just like a React class with only a render
>   method defined. Since no component instance is created for a
>   functional component, any ref added to one will evaluate to null.
>   Functional components do not have lifecycle methods, but you can set
>   `.propTypes` and `.defaultProps` as properties on the function.
>
> This pattern is designed to encourage the creation of these simple
>   components that should comprise large portions of your apps. In the
>   future, we’ll also be able to make performance optimizations specific
>   to these components by avoiding unnecessary checks and memory
>   allocations.

---

- #### What's the difference?

  This pattern is similar to the "traditional" one, except for the fact that you're using simple functions instead of methods defined in a class. This can be useful when you want to extract functions out of the class (e.g for readability and cleanliness sake).

  One important thing to note is that a functional component is just that - a *function*. It's not a class. As such, there's no global `this` object. This means that when you're doing a `render` you're basically creating a new instance of a `ReactComponent`, thus leaving out the possibility for these javascript objects to communicate with each other via some global `this`. This also makes the use of `state` and any life-cycle methods impossible as a consequence.

---

- #### How does my app benefit from it?

  **Performance**
  When you're using stateless functional components, React is clever enough to omit all "traditional" life-cycle methods, which turns out to be providing a fair amount of optimizations. The React team has stated that they are planning to implement further optimizations in the future for memory allocations and reducing the number of checks.

  **Adaptability**
  Because we're only talking about a function (and not a class), we don't need to worry about `state`, life-cycle methods, or other dependencies. Given the parameters, the function will always give the same output. As such, it's very easy to adapt such components wherever we want, which turns out to also make testing easier.

  > With React’s stateless functional components, each component can be easily tested in isolation. No mocking, state manipulation, special libraries, or tricky test harnesses are needed.

  **Encourages best practices**
  React is often compared to the **V** of the MVC pattern because it's meant for creating views. The "traditional" ways of creating components make it easy to "hack in" business logic (e.g with `state` or `ref`) into components that really should only handle render logic. They encourage laziness and writing smelly code. However, stateless functional components make it nearly impossible to take such shortcuts and force the better approach.

---

- #### When should I use the one over the other?

  Generally, using the new pattern is recommended whenever possible! If you only need a `render` method, but no life-cycle methods or `state`, use this pattern. Of course, sometimes you *do* need to use `state`, in which case you're fine using the traditional pattern.

  Facebook recommends using stateless components whenever rendering static presentational components. Then, if some kind of state is needed, simply wrap those in a stateful component to manage them by using its' `state` and sending down `props` to the stateless components.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the thorough answer. I'm using Granze's react-starterify git as my starting point and it uses const exclusively for the framework... but it would seem that for a dynamic webapp that having access to state and life-cycle would be crucial for so many things, no? I do notice a "App.propTypes = { children: React.PropTypes.object } in the App.js file. Maybe this is to store cross-component data?

Comment: I haven't used `react-starterify` to say, but the code snippet you are referring to is most likely just a type declaration. Perhaps someone with experience with `react-starterify` can shed some light.

Answer (score 2):

To be added, from react 15.5.0, React.createClass will be deprecated. They recommend you to move to ES2015 class or use arrow function.

> When React was initially released, there was no idiomatic way to create classes in JavaScript, so we provided our own: React.createClass.
>
> Later, classes were added to the language as part of ES2015, so we added the ability to create React components using JavaScript classes. Along with functional components, JavaScript classes are now the preferred way to create components in React.
>
> For your existing createClass components, we recommend that you migrate them to JavaScript classes.