# Javascript storing value of a class

Tags: javascript

when we do something like this

```
const something = class extends anything {
}
```

What does it mean or what does it do? Does it store the value of class in a Variable? and how will this be different from

```
class something extends anything {
}
```

Comment: [class expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class)

Comment: It stores a reference to a class. "and how will this be different from" --- you can override the `something` value in the second case.

Comment: `class`es in JavaScript are first-class objects. There are no special "Type" definitions, they're just passed around like normal references.

Comment: Not sure but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591277/react-differences-between-component-create-with-extend-class-and-simple-const?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "class" in javascript in the same way that they exist in class-based languages like Java. In JS, the class syntax is sugar over the same old constructor function. When you understand that, your question becomes easier to reason with.

This:

```
const something = class extends anything {
}
```

Is (roughly) analogous to this:

```
const something = function() {
}
something.prototype = Object.create(anything.prototype)
```

And the same similarity goes for these variants:

```
class something extends anything {
}

function something() {
}
something.prototype = Object.create(anything.prototype)
```

Functions are first class objects in javascript, which means they can be treated as values and passed around. The difference between `const something = class...` and `class something...`
 is that the first is a class expression (assigning a class like a value to a variable that can be passed around) and the second is a class declaration (declaring the class and giving it a name, but not assigning it to a variable), but they are interchangeable in most scenarios.

For clarification, when you do `something.prototype = Object.create(anything.prototype)`, this is the actual inheritance that Javascript uses. It roughly means that you take the "prototype" of a constructor function and use it as a base for the next one, and that means that whatever object that you create using `new something()` will have the prototype of `anything`, plus any other attributes that you need to add to `something.prototype`.

You can get more in-depth info here: [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@kevincennis/prototypal-inheritance-781bccc97edb)

Comment: Just to avoid confusion between es6 and previous versions it's worth to mention: functions are hoisted (just as a var is) and classes are not (just like const and let are not). So `function something() {}` is available anywhere in the code, but `const something = function () {}`, `class something {}` and anything `const` are only available after the execution gets to their declaration.

Comment: @SrThompson Can you please also add the meaning of this line? `something.prototype = Object.create(anything.prototype)` like if you can explain this as well in your answer

Comment: @KuchBhi edited, I hope that makes it clearer. Probably someone on the internet can explain it better than me though :)

Comment: Is it same as normal prototype for example `Anything.prototype.something = function () { //Somethinng }` Just here we don't have to do `new something ()`

Comment: @KuchBhi not exactly. `Anything.prototype.something = ...` adds a property "something" to Anything's prototype. `something.prototype = Object.create(anything.prototype)` creates a new object (not a reference) with `anything`'s prototype and assigns it as `something`'s prototype. You can later do `something.prototype.someOtherAttributeOrFunction = ...` and add to `something`'s prototype without affecting `anything`'s prototype

Answer (score 2):

Just to note that declaring `const something = code` means in practice that all of the following is impossible:

```
function something(){//code}
  var something;
  let something;
  class something{
//whatever
  }
```

That specific name is reserved, the purpose of `const` is that, otherwise, you could rewrite the class itself using the same name like this:

```
 var something = class anything {//code
  }

  var something = class anything {//code changes previous class
  }
```

And again, this is not possible:

```
class anything {//code
      }
class anything {//code changes previous class
      }
```

You can't change anything. So I think there is no practical difference between `const something = class` and `class something extends anything` because both are names reserved and "versions" of other classes.