# What is the difference for export default/const/class extends?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

There is a very good Tutorial for Gatsby on their website. Everything works fine but I've a problem to understand the difference in the starter templates.

What is the difference between the different react component usage in the starte templates? Why do they use `export default...` for the hello world example, `const IndesPage = () 0> (` for the default starter and `class BlogIndes extends React.Componenent` for the blog example.

**gatsby-starter-hello-world**

`export default () => <div>Hello world!</div>`

**gatsby-starter-default**

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  ...
)

export default IndexPage
```

**gatsby-starter-blog**

```
class BlogIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    ...

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default BlogIndex
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (ES6), export const vs export default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-default)

Comment: These are all React components, the first two are functional components and the last is a class component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react, differences between component create with extend class and simple const = function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591277/react-differences-between-component-create-with-extend-class-and-simple-const) and [React: when to use ES6 class based components vs. functional ES6 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097965) and [React functional stateless component, PureComponent, Component; what are the differences and when should we use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703675)

Answer (score 1):

**gatsby-starter-hello-world** and **gatsby-starter-default** are stateless component, a quote from the React documentation:

> These components must not retain internal state, do not have backing instances, and do not have the component lifecycle methods. They are pure functional transforms of their input, with zero boilerplate. However, you may still specify .propTypes and .defaultProps by setting them as properties on the function, just as you would set them on an ES6 class.

**gatsby-starter-blog** is a stateful component
It has a state, lifecycle hooks, a class component should be used whenever you need to work with state...

Hope this helps

Comment: gatsby-starter-hello-world is a stateless component, too.

Comment: What is the difference then between **gatsby-starter-hello-world** and **gatsby-starter-default**? When do I've to use the one over another?

Comment: And another question: I couldn't find that state in the **gatsby-starter-blog** (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/src/pages/index.js) Perhaps that is the reason why I'm wondering about this.