# cannot diplay the json data on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have testdata.json file which contains json data, when i try to execute the code below i am getting an error as "A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object". what should i do now?

this is `contestpreview.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

const ContestPreview = (contest) => {
  <div className = "contestPreview">
    <div>
      {contest.categoryName}
    </div>
    <div>
      {contest.contestName}
    </div>
  </div>
};
export default ContestPreview;
```

This my `app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

import ContestPreview from './ContestPreview';
class App extends React.Component {     
  state= { test : 7};
  render(){
    return(<div>
      <div>
        <Header message = "Naming contests"/>
      </div>
      <div>    
        <ContestPreview {...this.props.contests}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
};

export default App;
```

This is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import data from './testData';
console.log(data);
import App from './components/App';

ReactDom.render(
  <App contest = {data.contest}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ContentPreview` component doesn't return a React Component. It's a small error on your part, but you can fix this by either adding a `return` statement, or by replacing your curly-braces with parenthesis.

Like so:

```
const ContestPreview = (contest) => (
  <div className = "contestPreview">
    <div>
      {contest.categoryName}
    </div>
    <div>
      {contest.contestName}
    </div>
  </div>
);
export default ContestPreview;
```

**or**

```
const ContestPreview = (contest) => {
  return (
    <div className = "contestPreview">
      <div>
        {contest.categoryName}
      </div>
      <div>
        {contest.contestName}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ContestPreview;
```

The latter allows you to add some application logic before the return, if you want (though discouraged).

---

Since you're using a *stateless functional component*, you may find my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37170998/2030321) on the pros/cons of these interesting.

Good luck!