# How to set an initial API call in react ES6

Tags: reactjs

So the problem is as follows: I have a search function that get's an default value passed on from another place, the search works, but only when it gets a new input, hence if I'm passing "Dress" it wont call my api function before i change something in the input.

I've tried a bit of everything like **setInitialState()**, but without any noteworthy success.

As you can see I'm getting a **onTermChange** from my **Searchbar** that's passed to **handleTermChange** which then updates my products:[], but I need ***this.props.location.query*** to be the default search term, as this is the passed on variable.

```
  handleTermChange = (term)  => {
    const url = `http://localhost:3001/products?title=${term.replace(/\s/g, '+')}`;
    request.get(url, (err, res) =>  {
       this.setState({ products: res.body })
    });
  };

render () {
    return (
        <div className='col-md-12' style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}>
            <div className='row searchPageHeader' style={{ padding: '10px', backgroundColor: '#1ABC9C' }}/>
            <SideMenu />
            <SearchBar    onTermChange={this.handleTermChange}
                          defaultValue={this.props.location.query}/>
            <ProductList  products={this.state.products}
                          onProductSelect={selectedProduct => this.openModal(selectedProduct)}/>
            <ProductModal modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                          selectedProduct={this.state.selectedProduct}
                          onRequestClose={ () => this.closeModal() }/>
            <Footer />
        </div>
       );
}
```

Comment: So you want to automatically execute a search with the `location.query` value when the component mounts?

Comment: Yes, I want to automatically set my _products_ equal to the string that gets passed through _location.query_ so my location query should basically run through handleTermChange and update my productList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally just do the same logic in `componentDidMount()`, like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
  const url = `http://localhost:3001/products?title=${this.props.location.query}`;
  request.get(url, (err, res) =>  {
    this.setState({ products: res.body })
  });
}
```

Note that since you are doing an asynchronous call `products` won't be populated from the API result until a moment after the component is mounted. Make sure you initialize `products` in `initialState` (*I assume this returns an array, so initialize it as an empty array*).

---

**Opinion:** Since you are following the event handler naming conventions (i.e `onX` followed by `handleX`) I would avoid calling `handleTermChange()` inside `componentDidMount()` because the function name suggests it's bound to an event listener. So calling it directly is just bad practice in my opinion. So if you'd rather call a function in here, rather than writing out the logic like I did above, I would do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.changeTerm(this.props.location.query);
}

changeTerm = (term)  => {
  const url = `http://localhost:3001/products?title=${term.replace(/\s/g, '+')}`;
  request.get(url, (err, res) =>  {
    this.setState({ products: res.body })
  });
};

handleTermChange = (term) => {
  this.changeTerm(term);
}
```

Your `render()` remains unchanged. Maybe a stretch, but I prefer it this way.

Comment: I'm getting a "term.replace is not a function" error when doing what you proposed

Comment: @Sjohansen, that's probably because `term` isn't a string. Double-check you are passing `this.props.location.query`. Console it in your `render` to check.

Comment: My mistake, my _this.props.location.query_ returned an object with a string _q_, so when I changed that, it started working. Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick best-practice question: would it make sense to move most of function calls into my search function instead of having them in my routes?

Comment: Hard to answer. What functions are they?

Comment: The changeTerm, handleTermChange etc.

Comment: I just noticed that I'm also getting an 

"Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Search component."

Comment: By routes I assume you mean your views which contain the Searchbar. The best practice to try to create stateless components and have their parent or even grandparent manage their state. Ask yourself this: "*Does this component need to know its **own** state or should the parent know that?*". In my mind it makes more sense to have your view know what you searched for, rather than the Searchbar itself. The searchbar only accepts some text - how this text is managed is not relevant to it -- so pass it to your parent instead. Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170809/).

Comment: @Sjohansen, you probably searched for something and left the view before your API could respond to your query. This would execute the callback you have which tries to update the state of an unmounted component.

Comment: A sincere thanks for all the advice! I seem to have figured everything out, and got a little bit smarter as well!

Comment: @Sjohansen, glad I could help. Please consider upvoting the posts you found helpful - it increases visibility for future readers that may face similar issues.

Comment: my reputation is sadly still too low for that. However, will do in the future of course!