# unexpected token using stateless function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to avoid extends of Component as the component merely render data, it can be standalone.

```
const CountDown = () => {
    render(){
        return(
            <p>Countdown.jsx</p>
        )
    }
}

module.exports = Countdown
```

But what's wrong? I got unexpected token at `render(){ ... }`

Comment: I down voted because you didn't show any research where you tried to fix this on your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stateless functional components don't have the `render()` method... in fact they don't have any methods because they are a method themselves.

Try instead:

```
const CountDown = () => {
  return(
    <p>Countdown.jsx</p>
  )
}

module.exports = Countdown
```

or even:

```
const CountDown = () => <p>Countdown.jsx</p>
module.exports = Countdown
```

---

As a side-note, you might find [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170809/react-createclass-vs-es6-arrow-function/37170998#37170998) interesting. It's an in-depth explanation of stateless functional components.