# React Iterate and insert components based on count of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So say i have an array

```
var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

and i have a component 
CardContainer

```
class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
    render() { 
        return (
            <div> 
            <Card/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

what im trying to do is
create a number of Card components based on length/count of array "arr",
and also 
set the text of the div in the Card component from the array.

```
class Card extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
           <!--Print arr[i] val using this.props? -->
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So my output will be 4 cards with, 
array values printed on each card individually.

This is what ive come up with unsucessfully

```
class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
        var elements=[];
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            elements.push(<Card value=arr[i]/>);
        }
        return (
            <div> 
            {elements}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You were close, only forgot to populate the `elements` array with the Cards, so it's still empty after the loop finishes. And while using `map` as others suggest is the most idiomatic way to do it in React it still simply generates an array of components which can be generated using a `for` loop as well:

https://jsfiddle.net/mn0jy5v5/

```
class Card extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
            { this.props.value }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
    render() {
        var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
        var elements=[];
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
             // push the component to elements!
            elements.push(<Card value={ arr[i] } />);
        }
        /* the for loop above is essentially the same as
        elements = arr.map( item => <Card value={ item } /> );
        The result is an array of four Card components. */
        return (
            <div> 
            {elements}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work when I try to pass parameter to function as props. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

You almost got it right!

You missed the curly-braces around `arr[i]`. So a working code would look like:

```
class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
    var elements=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      elements.push(<Card value={arr[i]} />);
    }
    return (
      <div> 
        {elements}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

However I suggest you use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through the array:

> `map` calls a provided callback function **once for each element** in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results

---

So try this:

```
class CardContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];  
    return (
      <div> 
        {arr.map(item => <Card key={item} value={item} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

You can then access your value inside `Card` like this:

```
class Card extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        {this.props.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also rewrite your `Card` component into a [***stateless functional component***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170809/react-createclass-vs-es6-arrow-function/37170998#37170998), like this:

```
const Card = (props) =>   
  return (
    <div> 
      {props.value}
    </div>
  );
}
```

if you want it more compact:

```
const Card = props => <div>{props.value}</div>
```

Comment: thanks, how do i access the value using props within Card?

Comment: Thankyou, dig the stateless functional component approach,cheers!

Comment: While `map` is the usual way to do this it is not magic and doesn't do anything that can not be done using a `for` loop. OP's problem was not that they didn't use `map` but that the `elements` were an empty array even after the for loop finished ;)

Comment: @pawel, I actually didn't look carefully as to why the code didn't work for OP. I just provided the simplest solution. However, I did take a look now. The problem isn't that the `elements` array is empty, but because the code has a syntax error. It is missing the curly-braces around `<Card value={arr[i]} />` - which is invalid JSX. That said, I will update my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @ViVekH, updated answer with more details. Take a look.

Comment: @Chris  `push` has been edited into the question after I have posted my answer ;) The lack of curly braces is a problem as well.

Comment: @pawel, ah okay, didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use .map method https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
render() {
    var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
    return (
        <div>
         // curly braces for parenthesis
        {
           arr.map((item, index) => {
              <Card value={item} key={index} />
           });
        }
       </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this using map

```
 class CardContainer extends React.Component {   
        render() {
            var arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];

            return (
                <div> 
                {
    arr.map(function(value,i)
    {
    return <Card value={value} key={i}/>

    }  
    ) 
    }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can try passing an array to the cards class and dynamically generate elements accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/83859/

```
 class CardContainer extends React.Component {  
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.props=props;
            this.arr=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
        }
        render() { 
            return (
                <div> 
                <Card arr={this.arr}/> //pass your props value
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

**`your cards class here`**

```
class Card extends React.Component {   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.props=props; //set props value

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
            {
             // itterate through the array
             this.props.arr.map((value,index)=>(
              <div key={index}>{value}</div>
             ))
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: getting index undefined

Comment: which place ? new bee to react?

Comment: in Card you have the iteration , this.props.arr.map((value,index)=>(
              <div key={index}>{value}<div/>
             )), in the console it shows me index undefined , also you have closed the div as <div/> it should be </div> and in your constructors you have not put super();